# How to decide between CCCrypt or SecKeyEncrypt

Tags: ios, encryption

For an iPad application (ios5.0, arc) I need to encrypt the data going over to a web service that I'm using. On reading about encryption available via Apple, I've come across two APIs to do this : CCCrypt and SecKeyEncrypt. However, how should I decide which ones to use?

Thanks in advance for your help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SecKeyEncrypt is for Asymetric encryption like RSA. CCcrypt for symmetric encryption like AES, DES .,